# MySQL user events actions and sessions sequence

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sequence, partition

I have db on MySQL - dataset with users actions logs. We have next data collection logic - every user have it own user_id and we record log of event actions during user session.

| user_id | session_id | dateTime | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 2023-01-01 13:12:11 | login |
| 1 | aa | 2023-01-01 14:12:10 | buy |
| 1 | bb | 2023-01-02 11:12:10 | page |
| 2 | cc | 2023-01-01 10:11:01 | login |
| 2 | gg | 2023-01-03 11:12:11 | logout |
| 2 | gg | 2023-01-03 13:11:03 | click |
| 2 | gg | 2023-01-03 14:10:07 | logout |

The main goal is to prepare the MySQL query with raw data and add 2 new calculated columns: one with events action sequence during every user session and the second with session sequence during all user lifetime by SQL.

Expected output:

| user_id | session_id | dateTime | event | event_seq | session_seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 2023-01-01 13:12:11 | login | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | aa | 2023-01-01 14:12:10 | buy | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | bb | 2023-01-02 11:12:10 | page | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | cc | 2023-01-01 10:11:01 | login | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | gg | 2023-01-03 11:12:11 | logout | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | gg | 2023-01-03 13:11:03 | click | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | gg | 2023-01-03 14:10:07 | logout | 3 | 2 |

Comment: Hi - you haven't actually asked a question. Please update your question with the SQL that you've managed to write on your own and ask a question about a specific issue you are facing (hint: you probably need to use window functions)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT ds.*,
dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY user_id,session_id order BY session_id,`dateTime` ) AS event_seq,
dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY user_id  order BY user_id,session_id   ) AS session_seq
FROM dataset AS ds
ORDER BY user_id,session_id,`dateTime`;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM dataset;
+----+---------+------------+---------------------+--------+
| id | user_id | session_id | dateTime            | event  |
+----+---------+------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | aa         | 2023-01-01 13:12:11 | login  |
|  2 |       1 | aa         | 2023-01-01 14:12:10 | buy    |
|  3 |       1 | bb         | 2023-01-02 11:12:10 | page   |
|  4 |       2 | cc         | 2023-01-01 10:11:01 | login  |
|  5 |       2 | gg         | 2023-01-03 11:12:11 | logout |
|  6 |       2 | gg         | 2023-01-03 13:11:03 | click  |
|  7 |       2 | gg         | 2023-01-03 14:10:07 | logout |
+----+---------+------------+---------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ds.*,
    -> dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY user_id,session_id order BY session_id,`dateTime` ) AS event_seq,
    -> dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY user_id  order BY user_id,session_id   ) AS session_seq
    -> FROM dataset AS ds
    -> ORDER BY user_id,session_id,`dateTime`;
+----+---------+------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
| id | user_id | session_id | dateTime            | event  | event_seq | session_seq |
+----+---------+------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | aa         | 2023-01-01 13:12:11 | login  |         1 |           1 |
|  2 |       1 | aa         | 2023-01-01 14:12:10 | buy    |         2 |           1 |
|  3 |       1 | bb         | 2023-01-02 11:12:10 | page   |         1 |           2 |
|  4 |       2 | cc         | 2023-01-01 10:11:01 | login  |         1 |           1 |
|  5 |       2 | gg         | 2023-01-03 11:12:11 | logout |         1 |           2 |
|  6 |       2 | gg         | 2023-01-03 13:11:03 | click  |         2 |           2 |
|  7 |       2 | gg         | 2023-01-03 14:10:07 | logout |         3 |           2 |
+----+---------+------------+---------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

note: see if your MySQL Version supports WINDOW functions

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this using window functions.

```
WITH session_views
     AS (SELECT user_id,
                session_id,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY user_id) session_seq
         FROM   user_actions
         GROUP  BY user_id,
                   session_id)
SELECT user_actions.user_id,
       user_actions.session_id,
       user_actions.dateTime,
       user_actions.event,
       Row_number()
         OVER (
           partition BY user_actions.session_id) event_seq,
       session_views.session_seq,
FROM   user_actions
       LEFT JOIN session_views
              ON session_views.session_id = user_actions.session_id and session_views.user_id = user_actions.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1zjEIYCH)

```
SELECT logs.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id) as event_seq,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, session_id) AS session_seq
FROM logs;
```

You can use window functions `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`:

- `ROW_NUMBER()` enumerates rows inside of each partition which is grouped by `user_id, session_id` columns
- `DENSE_RANK()` consequently ranks rows inside each partition which is grouped by `user_id` column. The order is determined in `ORDER BY user_id, session_id` expression.

**[The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)**.